# PSTricks package giving xkeyval error

Tags: pstricks, xkeyval, pst-optexp

I have been trying to solve this error by myself but did not find a way.
  So if someone out there can help me, any help is greatly appreciated!

I use Texmaker to run MikTex 2.9.
I want to use the package PSTricks to draw something.

To do so, I run LaTex on an UTF8-formatted tex-file.
This is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

%\usepackage{pst-all}
%\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
%\usepackage{pst-all}
%\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](4,2)
  \optdiode[conn=-i](0,1)(4,1){Diode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

and it gives me an error message saying:

**! Package xkeyval Error: 'conn' undefined in families `,pstricks,pst-node,pst-t
ools,pst-plot,pst-eucl,pst-3d,pstricks-add,optexp'.**

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.46   \optdiodeconn=-i(4,1){Diode}

To check for outdated package versions I have here the \listfiles result:

```
scrbook.cls    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
pst-optexp.sty    2014/06/04 v4.10 Optical experimental setups with PSTricks
ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
pstricks.tex    2014/05/19 v2.54a `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
xkeyval.sty    2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex    2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
pst-fp.tex    2014/05/19 v2.54a `PST-fp' (hv)
xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvips.def    2014/04/23 v3.0j Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pst-node.tex    2014/03/25 1.33 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
pst-plot.sty    2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
multido.sty    2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)
multido.tex    2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
pst-plot.tex    2014/07/07 1.64 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
pst-eucl.sty    2014/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks pst-eucl.tex
pst-tools.sty    2012/01/01 package wrapper for pst-tools.tex (hv)
pst-tools.tex    2014/07/07 v1.64 `PST-tools' (hv)
pst-eucl.tex    2014/05/17 v1.51 `PST-eucl' (dr,hv)
pstricks-add.sty    2010/02/11 v. 0.14 package wrapper for pstricks-add.tex (hv)
pst-3d.sty    2009/07/28 package wrapper for pst-3d.tex (hv)
pst-3d.tex    2010/02/14 v1.11 `PST-3d' (hv)
pst-math.sty    2009/01/20 package wrapper for PSTricks pst-math.tex
pstricks-add.tex    2014/07/22 v3.75 `PSTricks-add' (hv)
pstricks-add.pro    2009/12/17 v. 0.23, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pstricks-add.cfg    2005/01/10 v0.1 addtional user stuff (hv)
environ.sty    2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
pst-optexp.pro
```

Anyone having an idea?

Comment: On my system it compiles fine. Is this a minimal file that does *not* compile for you?

Comment: yes, this does NOT compile for me.
It does compile if I change conn=-i to beam e.g. (which is another option).

Comment: But for whatever reason keys like conn cause an error ...

Comment: Finally I can reproduce your problem, compiling with LaTeX. I have no idea why such an error. However, if you add the `pdf` option to the document class and compile with `pdflatex` it does compile without an error. This is the first case I meet that compiles with pdflatex and not with latex, I must say.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask again but how did your working documentclass look exactly?

Comment: @Tobias: What is it exactly that you want to draw? Do you have a picture?

Comment: @Werner I want to draw my physics experimental setup which involves a lot of optical components (lenses, diodes, beams etc). Thus I was very happy to find the pst-optepx package. Right now I don't have a picture yet - first I want to be able to use pst-optex without error messages.

Comment: @Bernard: It does _not_ work with `pdflatex`. `auto-pst-pdf` does a  `latex` run in `batchmode`!

Comment: @Herbert:Maybe, but it's a fact that with pdflatex I do have a picture and with latex I do not, whence I conclude that auto-pst-pdf does the job.

Comment: No, you get the picture without the connection! `latex -interaction=batchmode <file>` creates a dvi file which can be converted to a pdf. And that is exactly what auto-pst-pdf does. But nevertheless the pdf is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no more an option `conn` in the current version (see documentation!) Use instead:

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](4,2)
  \optdiode(0,1)(4,1){Diode}
  \drawbeam[beaminsidefirst]{}(B)
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I did read the documentation on pstricks and opt-exp but I took an old pdf (from 2009?) instead of up to date documentation... -.-

Comment: Use always the command `texdoc pst-optexp` then you'll get the up-to-date version.